# Is there a way to create a dataframe by joining from a list in R?

Tags: r, loops, rstudio

I have a list named `ind_prov` and structured as follows:

1. It has 22 elements.
2. All elements are class "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame".
3. Each elements has three colmuns.

   - First column: fecha
   - Second Column: provincia
   - Third column: an element a vector named list_vars of length 22.

     - Example: names(ind_prov[[1]]) equals "fecha" "provincia" "emp_pob". emp_pob is the first element of vector list_vars.

I want a data.frame like this, but with the 22 elements:

```
> provincias <-
+   ind_prov[[list_vars[1]]] %>%
+   left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[2]]],
+             by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
+   left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[3]]],
+             by = c("fecha", "provincia"))
> provincias
# A tibble: 2,086 x 5
   fecha      provincia              emp_pob     ofc_pob   caje_pob
   <date>     <chr>                    <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2013-03-01 Monte Cristi         0.000184  0.0000117   0.0000235 
 2 2013-03-01 San Pedro de Macorís 0.00413   0.0000869   0.000799  
 3 2013-03-01 San Pedro de Macorís 0.00413   0.000191    0.000799  
 4 2013-03-01 El Seibo             0.000152  0.00000338  0.0000236 
 5 2013-03-01 El Seibo             0.000152  0.0000101   0.0000236 
 6 2013-03-01 Hato Mayor           0.000339  0.00000595  0.0000535 
 7 2013-03-01 Hato Mayor           0.000339  0.0000297   0.0000535 
 8 2013-03-01 Monte Plata          0.0000215 0.00000117  0.00000430
 9 2013-03-01 Monte Plata          0.0000215 0.000000782 0.00000430
10 2013-03-01 Azua                 0.000634  0.0000474   0.0000533 
# ... with 2,076 more rows
```

I DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS:

```
provincias <-
  ind_prov[[list_vars[1]]] %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[2]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[3]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia"))
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[4]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[5]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[6]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[7]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[8]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[9]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[10]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[11]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[12]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[13]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[14]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[15]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[16]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[17]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[18]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[19]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[20]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[21]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia")) %>%
  left_join(ind_prov[[list_vars[22]]],
            by = c("fecha", "provincia"))
```

Comment: `provincias  = purrr:reduce(list_vars, left_join, by = c("fecha", "provincia"))`

Comment: I tried but R gave this:   ```>   provincias <- 
+     purrr::reduce(list_vars, 
+                  left_join, 
+                  by = c("fecha", "provincia"))
Error in UseMethod("left_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "character"```

Comment: `purrr:reduce(list_vars, left_join, by = c("fecha", "provincia"))` is equivalent to the code that you "DO NOT WANT TO DO". Your error makes it sound like one of your list elements is a `character` vector, not a `tbl_df`. Please double check your list, and if you still have issues try to share a small subset of data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It worked with ```provincias <-  reduce(ind_prov,
                         left_join,
                         by = c("fecha", "provincia"))```